# SSRS where install the font?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Simple question that I can not found a simple answer. I am using a Reporting Server to generate my reports, and the reports use a custom font

My question is I need to install the custom font on all machines that will run the report or only on the server?

The company uses SSRS 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Installing the font on the reporting server and then enabling the font embedding should do the magic.

For font embedding, see this link:
[Exporting to a PDF File and Font Embedding.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159713(v=SQL.100).aspx)