# SSRS - Font with spaces

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, font-family

I have a font with a space in its name, and it is not recognized when displaying the report with IE11 (which is the browser I have to work with).

Strangely, it is recognized with IE8, but I can't use it...

If I manually change (via <kbd>F12</kbd>) the CSS from `font-family: Code 128;` to `font-family: "Code 128";` or `font-family: Code128;`, it displays correctly in IE11.

Is there a way to force SSRS to use quotation marks for `font-family` when rendering reports in HTML?

I couldn't find anything on this, and it seems that writing `"Code 128"` and `Code128` in the properties field doesn't work (*"Property value is not valid."*)

### EDIT

So I finally managed to get it to work for Html rendering by writing this:

```
FontFamily : ="&quot;Code 128&quot;"
```

But then the font isn't recognized when exporting to say `pdf`

Comment: I'm assuming you've already installed the font to your SSRS server as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717894/ssrs-where-install-the-font) describes.  It seems to me that SSRS allows spaces in the `font-family` property so if the font is installed on the local machine for development and the SSRS server with font embedding enabled, it should work.  Another less desirable solution would be to use placeholders for the text and use `HTML Markup` to simply change the font using HTML tags.

Comment: I indeed installed the font, my problem is that it generates `font-family: Code 128;` and this isn't recognized by IE11, but it is recognized by IE8

Comment: I've seen some sites that recommend entering the `font-family` property as an expression such as `="Code 128"`.  Perhaps give that a shot?

Comment: I just tried it, and it gives the same output (SSRS FontFamily field : `="Code 128"`, HTML output : `font-family: Code 128;` and so no rendered by IE11) I even tried `="""Code 128"""` but no luck, it outputs `font-family: "";`

Answer (score 0):

After seeing that using `="&quot;Code 128&quot;"` worked for HTML rendering, but not for pdf export, I tried the following, and it worked both for HTML and export:

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive, "&quot;Code 128&quot;", "Code 128")
```